# Convert JSON string from the server to an observable array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

In my javascript;

```
var tenderStatusChoices = '@Html.Raw(Model.TenderStatusChoices)';
```

I get the following data;

```
var tenderStatusChoices = '
    [{
        "Disabled": false,
        "Group": null,
        "Selected": true,
        "Text": "Open",
        "Value": "Open"
    }, {
        "Disabled": false,
        "Group": null,
        "Selected": false,
        "Text": "Successful",
        "Value": "Successful"
    }, {
        "Disabled": false,
        "Group": null,
        "Selected": false,
        "Text": "Unsuccessful",
        "Value": "Unsuccessful"
    }]';
```

I cannot use this JSon to populate a combo box in knockout, when I do I get the following error;

"The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined."

So how do I convert this Json string to an array that ko will understand?

The code that populates the combo is as follows;

```
<select id="TenderStatus" data-bind="
    options: tenderStatusChoices,
    optionsText: 'Text',
    optionsValue: 'Value',
    value: status">
</select>

var temp = '@Html.Raw(Model.TenderStatusChoices)';
var tenderStatusChoices = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + temp + ")"));

var Tender = function () {
    this.tenderId = ko.observable("@Model.Tender.TenderId");
    this.title = ko.observable("@Html.Raw(Model.Tender.Title)");
    this.estimateNumber = ko.observable("@Model.Tender.EstimateNumber");
    this.status = ko.observable("@Model.Tender.Status");
    this.tenderStatusChoices = ko.observableArray(tenderStatusChoices);
};

ko.applyBindings(Tender);
```

Comment: have you tried using the knockout mapping ? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the mapping plugin or loop through your data manually.

```
this.tenderStatusChoices = ko.observableArray(JSON.parse(temp));
```

Or use mapping plugin

```
this.tenderStatusChoices = ko.observableArray(ko.mapping.toJS(temp));
```

Comment: I would like the mapping solution to work, although it does not make any difference. I am not clear what the difference is between ToJS or fromJS. With the JSON.parse method, the application is falling over because: 'tenderStatusChoices' is undefined. I cannot see why this is.

Comment: toJS converts observableArray to plan array of objects while fromJSON is vise versa

Comment: The JSON.parse solution works. For that reason I give your answer a tick. The mapping solution does not work for some reason.